# Make the bars of bar chart clickable using aChart Engine

Tags: java, android, graph, charts

Using this code to show Bar chart using aChart Engine. Now I want to add click or touch event to the single bar of the chart,. but there is no Onclick or Ontouch event for this. How can I set Click listener to the bars?

```
public class BarGraph {

    public Intent getIntent(Context context) {

        int y[] = { 25, 10, 15, 20 };

        CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("Bar1");
        for (int i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            series.add("Bar" + (i + 1), y[i]);
        }

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataSet = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset(); // collection
                                                                            // of
                                                                            // series
                                                                            // under
                                                                            // one
                                                                            // object.,there
                                                                            // could
                                                                            // any
        dataSet.addSeries(series.toXYSeries()); // number of series

        // customization of the chart

        XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer(); // one renderer for
                                                            // one series
        renderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
        renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 5.5d);
        renderer.setLineWidth((float) 10.5d);

        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); // collection
                                                                                // multiple
                                                                                // values
                                                                                // for
                                                                                // one
                                                                                // renderer
                                                                                // or
                                                                                // series
        mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
        mRenderer.setChartTitle("Demo Graph");
        // mRenderer.setXTitle("xValues");
        mRenderer.setYTitle("Rupee");
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
        mRenderer.setShowGridX(true); // this will show the grid in graph
        mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);
        // mRenderer.setAntialiasing(true);
        mRenderer.setBarSpacing(.5); // adding spacing between the line or
                                        // stacks
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
        // mRenderer.setYAxisMin(.5);
        mRenderer.setXAxisMax(5);
        mRenderer.setYAxisMax(50);
        //
        mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "Income");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "Saving");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "Expenditure");
        mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "NetIncome");
        mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
        mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);

        // mRenderer

        // will fix the chart position
        Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(context, dat`enter code here`aSet,
                mRenderer, Type.DEFAULT);

        return intent;
    }

}
```

To get the ClickListener I have tried to the code below:

```
ChartFactory.getBarChartView(context, dataSet, mRenderer,Type.DEFAULT).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Log.d("============view", "Onclick");

             }
             });
```

Then the event  doesn't fire   ...

Comment: What is the Problem? What is your Question? What does not work? Have you got any errors? What have you tried? What have you searched for?

Comment: I want to make the single bars of chart clickable ...

Comment: To repeat myself: What does not work? Have you got any errors? What have you tried? What have you searched for? I'm sorry, but with your provided Information it seems like "Here's my code, fix it because I don't want to"...

Comment: Modified the question ...

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue, so I think I know where you stuck.

You need this line in your onClick method which will give you control of selected bar or dataPoint (depends on the type of a chart):

```
SeriesSelection seriesSelection = chartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
```

Where chartView is your GraphicalView element.

Now you have selected your element from the graph, and you have a chance to use it in according with your needs.

Good practice is to check is it null, that would mean you have clicked the empty space on the chart. For example:

```
if (seriesSelection == null) {
    // do something or not
} else {
    // do something cool
}
```

You can access the data of clicked field with these methods:

```
seriesSelection.getSeriesIndex() // in case you have more than one series
seriesSelection.getPointIndex()  // gets place in a series 
seriesSelection.getValue()       // gets value for Y axis
seriesSelection.getXValue()      // gets value of X axis
```

Hope this helps!